# Removing empty group spaces in barcharts of ggplot2/lattice

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

This follows up on my Q&A regarding plotting defined groups using barchart in lattice. So following the solution to that little exercise, I've realised that R plots the data as it appears in the dataframe and leaves spaces between each bar, when the next row of data is allocated to another space on the barchart. If you look at the plot you'll understand what I mean:

```
> data.frame(SOExample2)
   Study.ID Diagnosis   Level
1         1    Cancer 1040.58
2         2    Cancer  810.92
3         3    Cancer 2087.80
4         4    Cancer 3959.02
5         5    Cancer 3648.48
6         6    Cancer 1191.74
7         7    Cancer 1156.90
8         8    Cancer 2705.56
9         9    Cancer  827.26
10       10    Cancer  867.16
11       11    Cancer  575.10
12       12    Cancer  699.85
13       13    Cancer 1121.86
14       14    Cancer 1830.62
15       15    Cancer 4203.01
16       16    Cancer  874.59
17       17    Cancer 1037.20
18       18    Cancer 1398.56
19       19    Cancer  910.49
20       20    Cancer  725.60
21       21    Cancer  894.05
22       22    Cancer 1489.25
23       23    Cancer 1518.76
24       24    Cancer  821.60
25       25    Cancer  530.35
26       26    Cancer 1191.80
27       27    Cancer 1920.12
28       28    Cancer 1330.60
29       29    Cancer  835.95
30       30    Cancer  525.22

require(lattice)
SOExample2$group<-ifelse(Level>median(Level),1,0)
barchart(Level~factor(group), data=SOExample2, groups=Study.ID)
```

This gives me the following barchart:

[image: Read the chart from left to right to understand how R makes spaces between the groups]

Similarly, you can do the same in `ggplot2`, but the same thing occurs:

```
require(ggplot2)
g1<-ggplot(SOExample2, aes(x=group, y=Level))
g1+geom_histogram(stat="identity")+facet_grid(.~group)+labs(x="Group")+labs(y="Levels")
```

[image: The same plot made with ggplot]

So, any ideas on how to remove these empty spaces?

Cheers,

Oliver

Comment: In Lattice: use the function resizePanels() of the latticeExtra package. Example is shown here: http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/#resizePanels&theme=default

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Study.ID` as you x values and convert them to factor to ensure that values aren't interpreted as numeric. Then for the `ggplot2` solution inside the facet_grid() add argument `scale="free"` to remove empty levels.

```
ggplot(SOExample2,aes(factor(Study.ID),y=Level))+
             geom_bar(stat="identity")+
             facet_grid(.~group,scales="free")
```

[image]

Comment: You my dear Sir are a genius!!! Very, very nice work. Worked perfectly!!!!! Thanks a mill!

Comment: Oh and by the way, is there anyways to add a horizontal line at the median(level) through the whole plot, say in red? 
Thanks a mill for everything.

Comment: Just add line `+geom_hline(aes(yintercept=median(Level)),color="red")` to code in my answer.